# zend framework 2: Unable to render template … resolver could not resolve to a file in live server

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am facing a problem in live server. The site is quite fine in local machine. But i am getting error in live server. Here is the live server [link](http://hifiquiz.tuizo.com/public/admin/)

The module config like following:

```
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(

        'Admin\Controller\Admin' => 'Admin\Controller\AdminController',

    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
       'admin' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'aliases' => array(
        'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' => 'my_auth_service',
    ),
    'invokables' => array(
        'my_auth_service' => 'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService',
    ),
),
// The following section is new and should be added to your file
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'admin' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/admin[/][:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id' => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Admin',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ), 
    ),
),
```

);
I am checking couple of times but getting everything is ok. Can anyone guess what is the error behind getting this error in live server. The error is:

```
Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "admin/admin/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file
```

I will be grateful if any one give a idea how i will solve this problem. Thanks for kind attention.

Comment: Did you verify that admin.phtml exists and is in the right location?

Comment: Yes, the required phtml exists and working fine in local machine

Comment: maybe i'm wrong, but 'template_path_stack' not need to have part : 'admin' =>
And try to do a 'template_map' => array() instead.

Comment: What is the full path (including filename) to the missing template?

Comment: path is admin/admin/index. The site in now live. Here is the link. http://hifiquiz.tuizo.com/public/admin/

Comment: Also please add your controller-action `AdminController -> indexAction()` code in your question.

Comment: Hi, same problem for me , i fixed, the name of folder was wrong, folders should be : view\admin\admin\index.phtml